# Why this code does not call a copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I have expected to have 2 copy constructor calls, one for return by value and one for pass argument by value. But it does not call copy constructor even a single time:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(){}

    MyClass (const MyClass &)
    {
        cout << "copy" <<endl;
    }
};

MyClass f()
{
    return MyClass();
}

void g(MyClass i)
{
    i;
}

int main() 
{

    f();
    g(MyClass());
    return 0;
}
```

Why?

Comment: copy elision ! Still the same test ? ; )

Comment: [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: Because the compiler performs copy elision. Compile it with `--no-elide-constructors` and you will have them called.

Comment: [It is called if you use the right options.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/107fb4df2a8e128b)

Comment: @quantdev yes, the same test :))